# writing a bmp file of a checkerboard in mips assembler

Tags: assembly, mips, fopen, fwrite, bmp

hi i am required to write a program in mips assembler where i am to create a checkerboard which is too be saved and written to a bmp file, compile this program it has a problem with writing the file because it jumps straight to my error message could someone please help me with this problem. Here is the code:

```
.data

file_open_error:    .asciiz "Open file error\n"
bmp_file:   .asciiz "chkboard.bmp"

.text
main:
    #----Write .BMP file (header+data)----

    li  $v0, 13         # open file
    la  $a0, bmp_file   # file path
    li  $a1, 0x8301    # flags WRITE|CREATE|TRUNCATE|BINARY

    li  $a2, 0x1a4      # 0644 UNIX mode (rw-r--r--)
    syscall
    bgez    $v0, write_file
    li  $v0, 4          # print string
    la  $a0, file_open_error
    syscall

write_file:
    li  $v0, 10         # exit the program
    syscall
```

Comment: Use a debugger/simulator to step through the code and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: i said where it goes wrong it does not branch if greater or equal to zero but goes straigt to file_open_error message and i dont know why?? any help?

Comment: It wasn't clear which error you meant. Also, if it's a file open error, reduce your code to just have a file open. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: it replies with file_open because thats the text i entered its not necessarily a file open, it jumps to my error message but it finishes compiling without errors. im going to ask politely could u actually look at the code not just enter the most generic answers cause ive already tried everything i can and that is why im on this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
li  $a1, 0x8301    # flags WRITE|CREATE|TRUNCATE|BINARY
```

Not sure where you got the values from, but there is no `BINARY` in standard unix, and the others are `O_WRONLY=1`, `O_CREAT=0x40` and `O_TRUNC=0x200`, so the correct value is `0x241`.

This applies only if the given environment uses the unix values of course. `SPIM` does, but `MARS` for example is documented to only implement three flag values: `0` for read-only, `1` for write-only with create, and `9` for write-only with create and append. It ignores mode.

You forgot to say what you are using.

Comment: im using mars im sorry so im assuming i want to use 9 with a ignore mode yes?